# What is the difference "setter of React.useState" and "this.setState" during update of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I clicking on the button of AppFunctional the component doesn't update, but state is changed. In AppClass all right.

In both cases mutating the original state with "push", but I cant understand what is the difference.

Thanks in advance.

```
const List = ({ items }) => {
  return <h1>{items.join("-")}</h1>;
};

class AppClass extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [1],
  };

  addItem = () => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    items.push(2);
    this.setState({
      items,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add Item</button>
        <List items={items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const AppFunctional = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([1]);

  const addItem = () => {
    setItems((state) => {
      state.push(2);
      return state;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add Item</button>
      <List items={items} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are reference types, so this code means you are returning the same object, despite the fact that you have pushed another value meanwhile

```js
setItems((state) => {
   state.push(2);
   return state;
});
```

For the `useState` hook to understand that there's a change, you need to return another reference, so just copy the array:

```js
setItems((state) => {
   state.push(2);
   return state.slice();
});
```

or, better: The spread operator will copy all items from `state` into a new array, and you are also appending the 2 at the end.

```js
setItems((state) => [...state, 2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**useState** is a `functional` component  hook to set initial state and provides a callback method to update state whereas **setState** is a `class` component method to update state

Answer (score 0):

Well useState is for functional components and setState for class components, but if you want to understand how and why, React in classes depends on the "this" to trigger changes (rerenders) thats why it has to treat classes differently and use the "this" keyword with the state aka "this.setState" and "this.state" or "this.props"

i highly recommend Dan Abramov explanation of the differences between those:
https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/